# Makefile that generates obj files in subdirectory in Windows nmake

Tags: c, makefile, subdirectory, nmake, object-files

I am using **nmake** to compile my program that uses a makefile. I am trying the obj **(.o)** files to be placed in a separate directory than **C** files. Here is the makefile:

```makefile
!IFDEF DEBUG
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CDEBUGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION)
AOPT = $(AFLAGS_LIB) $(ADEBUGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION)
!ELSE
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CNODBGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION)
AOPT = $(AFLAGS_LIB) $(ANODBGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION)
!ENDIF

#################### Collect build files #####################################

CORE_HDRS =           \
    i_core.h          \
    i_cver.h          \
    i_target.h        \
    i_subbus.h        \
    v_core.h          \
    v_ioctl.h         \
    v_subbus.h        \
    v_target.h        \
    volcano6.h

CORE_OBJS =           \
    $(OBJPATH)/v_activable.$(O) \
    v_busoff_int.$(O) \
    v_c_act.$(O)  \
    v_c_con.$(O)  \
    v_c_dis.$(O)  \
    v_c_ini.$(O)  \
```

Looking at the **CORE_OBJS** I am using **$(OBJDIR)** with first object file while no prefix with rest. 
The issue is  **$(OBJPATH)/v_activable.$(O)** is not compiling at all. While rest of files are compiled and .o files are put in same directory as .c files. 
Here is code **makefile** part that compile's the code.

```makefile
OBJS = $(CORE_OBJS)


all: __prebuild__ __library__ __postbuild__

__prebuild__:
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "********************* Build started ****************************"

__dispopts__:
    @echo '*** Compiler: $(CC)'
    @echo "*** Compiler options: $(COPT)"
    @echo "*** Assembler options: $(AOPT)"
    @echo '*** Archiver: $(AR)'
    @echo "*** Archiver options: $(ARFLAGS)"
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "******************** Code generation ***************************"

__postbuild__:
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "********************* Build finished ***************************"

__library__: __dispopts__ $(OBJS)
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "******************** Creating library **************************"
    -@$(AR) $(ARFLAGS)
#################### Inference rules #########################################

.c.$(O):
    @echo Compiling $<
    @$(CC) $(COPT) $<

.$(S).$(O):
    @echo Assembling $<
    @$(AS) $(AOPT) $<
```

Can any one please see and tell me what exactly is the issue. I have tried rule:

```makefile
$(OBJPATH)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
```

**But nmake doesn't recognize this rule.** 
Here is what compiler options

```makefile
CFLAGS_LIB = -D__FAR_DATA -DUSE_LARGE_IMMEDIATE_FRAME_MASK -CpuHCS12X -Cc -Mb -Wpd -F2 -Rpt -Ot -Onu -Onf -Ol0 -OnB -Onbt -Onca -Oncn -One -OnP -Ont $(SUPPRESSIONS)

CNODBGFLAG = -NoDebugInfo -NoPath


COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CNODBGFLAG)
```

Comment: NMAKE is usually used on a Window platform. On windows file paths use the "\" symbol and command options use the "/" symbol. On linux and Mac a file path uses the "/" symbol and options usually use the "-" symbol. I see your are using the "/" symbol in a path. This is not normal in NMAKE. Perhaps that is your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have used both "/", "\". But the issue is still there.
Actually when I specify some path for obj files the compiler expects the source file to be in same directory. But I want source file and object file in different directories.

Comment: Which compiler and assembler are you using? The compilation commands are not changing the object folders. To change it we need to know which compilers. Is it GCC, CL or what?

Comment: I am using compiler from diab 5.9.1.6

Answer (score 0):

I do not have The Diab or CGT compiler tools, so cannot test my suggestions, but it is clear that your makefile is not using the [correct options](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-invoke.htm#2999761) to redirect the object files.

I'm assuming that the macro `OBJPATH` is where you want the objects to be sent to by the compiler.

If this is the case, then you will need to add that to the name of *every* object file, like this:

```
CORE_OBJS =           \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_activable.$(O) \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_busoff_int.$(O) \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_c_act.$(O)  \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_c_con.$(O)  \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_c_dis.$(O)  \
    $(OBJPATH)\v_c_ini.$(O)
```

Note that we are using the `\` symbol for two different purposes. This is noted in the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/43064).

The next part that has to be changed are the compiler flags to redirect the objects to the desired location. This can be done here:

```
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CNODBGFLAG) -c -o $@
```

This is using the [target macros as shown in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933742.aspx).

For the [CGT compiler the options are expressed as **--out=**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru187u/spru187u.pdf) and the rule would be:

```
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CNODBGFLAG) --compile-only --out=$@
```

One should not need to add a further rule for the compilation as it is handled here already:

```
.c.$(O):
        @echo Compiling $<
        @$(CC) $(COPT) $<
```

However, this needs to be amended to [add the directories where the files reside](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933236.aspx). The best source for this is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/841694/4370109). Consequently this should be amended to:

```
{$(SRC_DIR)}.c{$(OBJPATH)}.$(O):
        @echo Compiling $<
        @$(CC) $(COPT) $<
```

Finally, [just in case your suffix `$(O)` is different to the standards recognised by `nmake`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898797/why-does-nmake-ignore-my-implicit-rule/11057088#11057088) it might be sensible to [confirm the suffixes with the directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d82af2ab.aspx):

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .$(O)
```

So this rule that you added:

```
$(OBJPATH)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
```

made it worse both by using the wrong path and overriding the existing rule and so should be deleted.

I have now tested this in a makefile, just in case I overlooked something, and it works for me on my test files. My version of the makefile is simplified as I don't use an assembler, but it does demonstrate that it ale to maintain the sources and objects in different directories as you needed. More changes would need to be made to link the objects into the library by using appropriate options for the linker. I have used `gcc` to simulate this:

```
!IFDEF DEBUG
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CDEBUGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION) 
AOPT = $(AFLAGS_LIB) $(ADEBUGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION) 
!ELSE
COPT = $(CFLAGS_LIB) $(CNODBGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION)
AOPT = $(AFLAGS_LIB) $(ANODBGFLAG) $(LIB_OPTION) 
!ENDIF

#################### Collect build files #####################################

# Set macro for object file type
O=o
OBJPATH=obj
SRC=src
AR=gcc
ARFLAGS=-o library.exe $(OBJS)     

CORE_OBJS =           \
    $(OBJPATH)\one.$(O) \
    $(OBJPATH)\two.$(O) 

#append flag for directing object to their directory

COPT = $(COPT) -c -o $@

OBJS = $(CORE_OBJS)

.SUFFIXES: .c .$(O)


all: __prebuild__ __library__ __postbuild__

__prebuild__:
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "********************* Build started ****************************"

__dispopts__:
    @echo '*** Compiler: $(CC)'
    @echo "*** Compiler options: $(COPT)"
    @echo "*** Assembler options: $(AOPT)"
    @echo '*** Archiver: $(AR)'
    @echo "*** Archiver options: $(ARFLAGS)"
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "******************** Code generation ***************************"

__postbuild__:
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "********************* Build finished ***************************"

__library__: __dispopts__ $(OBJS)
    @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @echo "******************** Creating library **************************"
    -@$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) 
#################### Inference rules #########################################



{src}.c{$(OBJPATH)}.$(O):
    @echo Compiling $(CC) $(COPT) $<
    @$(CC) $(COPT) $<
```

And the output shows the builds and links working:

```
C:\Users\Brian>nmake /nologo /f Makefile
----------------------------------------------------------------
"********************* Build started ****************************"
'*** Compiler: gcc'
"*** Compiler options:    -c -o __dispopts__"
"*** Assembler options:   "
'*** Archiver: gcc'
"*** Archiver options: -o library.exe obj\one.o  obj\two.o"
----------------------------------------------------------------
"******************** Code generation ***************************"
Compiling gcc -c -o obj\one.o src\one.c
Compiling gcc -c -o obj\two.o src\two.c
----------------------------------------------------------------
"******************** Creating library **************************"
----------------------------------------------------------------
"********************* Build finished ***************************"
```

Comment: Hi Brian,

I have tried this again but the issue is still there. 
$(OBJPATH)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
This rule isn't working. Compiler expects the source file to be in same folder as of object file. 
And this issue in not of compiler. As Now I have changed the compiler. Now I am using "cgt" of Code Composer Studio.

Comment: @MuhammadImranAfzal  I have now fixed the answer and included details on using the CGT compiler.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you very much for the answer. But I still have some issue with this thing. Can you please send/post your test program. May be I am missing something.
Thank you for such an extensive and detail search on this topic.

Comment: @MuhammadImranAfzal My example makefile is now added